# Composition using foldr SML

Tags: sml, fold

Is there any way to do something like a(b(c(5))) from a variable that contains the functions?

The code would be something like that:

```
val a = fn x => x + 10
val b = fn x => x * x
val c = fn x => (x - 2) * 3
val fs = [a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `op` to the composition operator `o` so that it can be used as a function, and then use that function with `foldr` to fold the list of functions down to a single function. Use the identity function as an initial value.

Thus, `foldr (op o) identity [a, b, c]` is equivalent to `a o (b o (c o identity))`, where `identity` is the identity function:

```ml
fun identity x = x;
```

Using the posted definitions for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `fs` it's not too bad to write OP example as a one-liner:

```
- (foldr (op o) (fn x => x) fs) 5;
val it = 91 : int
- a(b(c 5));
val it = 91 : int
```

It's a bit easier if `identity` has been defined, but even nicer to define a higher-order function to abstract this away:

```ml
fun composeList fs = foldr (op o) (fn x => x) fs;
```

```
- composeList fs 5;
val it = 91 : int
```

Comment: If we rewrite `fun composeList fs = (foldr (op o) (fn x => x) fs);` as `fun composeList fs = foldr (op o) (fn x => x) fs;` by eliding the extraneous parentheses, it becomes clear this can be written as `val composeList = foldr (op o) (fn x => x);` utilizing currying.

Comment: @Chris -- that last part won't work because of [SML's value restriction](https://users.cs.fiu.edu/~smithg/cop4555/valrestr.html). I went ahead and removed the outer parentheses in the `composeList` definition, though.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: @adabsurdum Please, I've tried to just run this: 
fun composeList fs = foldr (op o) (fn x => x) fs;
composeList fs 5;

but I am still getting error: Error: unbound variable or constructor: fs   Could please somebody explain why? thx

Comment: @Piranha -- `fs` is a list of functions defined by the OP in the original question. My `composeList` function returns a function composed from a list of functions; you need to provide such a list. If you just want to test `composeList` you can enter the OP definitions for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `fs` found in the original question. After that `fs` will no longer be unbound.

Comment: @Piranha -- just to be clear, `fs` in the _definition_ of `composeList` is a _parameter_ of the function, but `fs` in the expression `composeList fs 5;` is an _argument_ given to the function. These are not the same thing; in the definition we are using a value which we will call `fs` in the function body, but in the expression we are passing a value identified by `fs` to the function (which will coincidentally be called `fs` within the function also). The expression `composeList fs 5;` expects there to be such a value in the environment. The names don't have to be the same; this could confuse